# How can I access an existing flash shared object?

Tags: flash, flash-media-server, shared-objects

I am trying to access a flash shared object using `sharedObject.getLocal("sharedObjectName");`

But, it always creates a new object and doesn't locate the existing object, then I searched the location where it saves the object and I got this location from the internet: `c:/Documents and Settings/username/Application Data/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects`

But, I could not get this directory in my windows XP.

Anyone please help me to access my shared object which is residing in my flash media server\application folder..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash Media Server shared object can be read in next ways:

- via [Admin Console](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flashmediaserver/3.0/docs/help.html?content=04_adminconsole_04.html) - must fit you;
- via custom fms code that will read SharedObjects and get result back to client side - long way.

Comment: Thanks I got access to my shared object but now one more problem that i faced. It has different level of hierarchy and i don't know how to access each level of shared object is there any way to access this please help...Thanks in advance!

Comment: SharedObject from folder "aaa" can be accessed from instance named "aaa", SharedObject from subfolder "aaa/bbb" can be accessed from instance "aaa" by path "aaa/bbb" or from instance "bbb". If I understood you correctly.

Comment: you are right i accessed SO by instance name but it displayed me just ....................................... and nothing, when i debug the application and show data then it showed me data hierarchy so what is the issue why i am not getting actual data of shared object..??